# You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. Vercel

Tags: reactjs, package.json, vercel

I just published my React app to vercel, the problem occurs when I make a call from my API, when I see the response from the server "Network" I get this error "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app". I have seen some problems regarding this and it seems that the problem may be in the package.json file, to be more precise in proxy, in this is the endpoint for my API:

```
"proxy": "https://URL"
```

Regarding the API, it is published on Heroku.

I have tested the project locally and the program works correctly, but when I run it in vercel I get the error.

[image]

just to show an example of how I consume my API this is an example.

```
const data = await axios.get("/places")
```

I have already restarted my server on heroku but the problem still continues